# Cannot connect to Azure Data Warehouse (now called Synapse) using SQLAlchemy

Tags: sql-server, sqlalchemy

I am trying to use python's sqlalchemy library for connecting to microsoft azure data warehouse. and receiving the following error:

`[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]111214;An attempt to complete a transaction has failed. No corresponding transaction found. (111214)`

The current code that I have tried:

```py
import sqlalchemy
import urllib

params = urllib.quote_plus("Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=<server-host>.database.windows.net,1433;Database=<database>;Uid=<user>@<server-host>;Pwd=<password>;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;")
engine = sqlalchemy.engine.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params)
engine.connect()
```

I can't seem to understand where the error is...is it db side or is my ODBC connection not right? I pulled it out of the Azure portal so I doubt that could be the case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ended up using this for the engine instead. Had to add connect_args.

`engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s' % params, echo=True, connect_args={'autocommit': True})`

Comment: that worked for me, thanks! It also works for Azure Synapse dedicated SQL Pools (it may be obvious because that's the new name of Azure Data Warehouse, but still useful to know for future readers)